# How to use SQL VALUE substitution in Delete statement with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use VALUES substitution with a delete statement for SQL Server.

The following doesn't work, however. I'm at a little bit of a loss as to whether there is a straightforward way of making this happen.

What am I missing? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
DELETE
FROM [dbo].[Jobs_Current]
WHERE (jobNo = ? AND Name = ?)
VALUES (1234, 'Mr Ape')
```

Comment: If you are passing in parameters from a client app you should use their parameterization

Comment: Got to be honest, this doesn't really help. The answer below was quite good and got me to the level of understanding I needed, and allowed me to chase down some extra terms.

Comment: What I meant to say was that you should use whatever client language you have to parameterize this query, it would probably look like this `DELETE FROM [dbo].[Jobs_Current] WHERE (jobNo = @jobNo AND Name = @name)` and you don't need a `VALUES` clause (which doesn't work like that with `DELETE` anyway, as @Gordon has shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want this:

```
DELETE jc
    FROM [dbo].[Jobs_Current] jc JOIN
         (VALUES (1234, 'Mr Ape')) v(jobNo, name)
         ON jc.jobNo = v.jobNo AND jc.Name = v.Name;
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks. What do jc, and v indicate here? also name and Name?

Comment: @anakaine . . . Those are table aliases -- abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: Thank you very much fro the example and pointing out what terms I should be looking up, I can go hunting for info from here.

Comment: Some examples in documentation for [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)